# UIScrollView setting contentInset in viewWillLayoutSubviews or viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, uiscrollview

so this question is not about a specific problem, but a general coding question.
Until now, I often used `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to set a new contentInset for my `UIScrollViews`. The reason is simple, in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` `self.topLayoutGuide.length` is set correctly, when e.g. rotating.
But today I wondered:
*Why not set the `contentInset` in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, shouldn't it be safer to do so there?*
The reason why I wondered is:
*Shouldn't it be better to set the `contentInset` before laying out the `UIScrollView` than setting it afterwards? The automatic scrolling for example may behave better if doing it this way?*
Maybe I'm just overthinking all this.
What do you think about this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you just set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES` inside your view controller and let the system take care of it for you, or do you need some kind of custom insets?

EDIT

I'm not sure it makes a difference, although it's difficult to know for sure without trying it. As you're just adjusting the insets, it actually should really matter if it's set before or after the layout pass is done, as it doesn't change any of your constraints or trigger another layout pass. Unless you're noticing a particular issue with scrolling on rotation, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Comment: I can, and i do. But the question wasn't about a specific problem i have with insets, but how to generally set custom insets. When you have a custom top inset, e.g. `self.topLayoutGuide.length + 44`, should you do set it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, thats the question

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: In some projects yes, in some others no. But like i said, i don't have problems with the `contentInsets`. I asked this question to find out about, where it's best to set the `contentInsets` if you have custom ones.

Comment: See my edit, in summary, I don't think it makes any difference